# How to display total number of comments in high chart on each plotted point?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

In my website, I want to display Average rating, Regression line and number of comments posted in HighCharts.

On HighCharts, I just want to plot Average rating, Regression line.But in tool-tip I want to display number of comments posted along with Average rating, Regression line.

For more idea,I attached screenshots.Please help me to do this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Extra informations like no of comments are kept in point object parameter or this is extra serie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [tooltip.positioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.positioner) setting to position the tooltip wherever you would like. The following is a code sample derived from  [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/tooltip/positioner/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        tooltip: {
            positioner: function () {
                return { x: 10, y: 35 };
            },
        },


    });
});
```